# Set HWND on CreateWindow appears to fail

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, createwindow

I'm coming from C# and very new at this so please bear with me.

I have a `MainWindow` class which has some private `HWND` variables. One for the window itself, and one for each of the controls. I assume I need to keep track of them, or that it will make things easier later?

Anyway, I've got:

```
class GUIMain
{
private:
    HINSTANCE hInstance;
    HWND hWnd; // The windows itself
    HWND cmdGenerate, cmdQuit; // 2 buttons
```

I've got a private method called `initialise(HWND hWnd)` which is called on `WM_CREATE` and it adds all the controls to the window:

```
void MainWindow::initialise(HWND hWnd)
{
  this->hWnd = hWnd;

  cmdGenerate = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("&Generate..."),
                             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                             6, 6, 150, 25,        
                             hWnd, (HMENU)1, 0, 0);

  cmdQuit     = CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("&Quit"),
                             WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                             6, 37, 150, 25,        
                             hWnd, (HMENU)2, 0, 0);
}
```

however this does not seem to put the buttons on the window. In fact, when I debug I can see that it's not even getting past the first line. What is strange is that when I change it to this:

```
void MainWindow::initialise(HWND hWnd)
{
  //this->hWnd = hWnd;

  /*cmdGenerate = */CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("&Generate..."),
                                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                                 6, 6, 150, 25,        
                                 hWnd, (HMENU)1, 0, 0);

  /*cmdQuit     = */CreateWindow(TEXT("BUTTON"), TEXT("&Quit"),
                                 WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD,
                                 6, 37, 150, 25,        
                                 hWnd, (HMENU)2, 0, 0);
}
```

it seems to work fine.

Logic would seem to suggest that assigning the private `HWND` variables the value of the `CreateWindow` function return is causing problems, but I have done this before and not had a problem?

The only difference between my previous code and this code is that I am now using classes whereas before (while I was learning) I just had everything in `WinMain` and `WndProc`.

WinMain: http://pastebin.com/j54vW9gc
Header File: http://pastebin.com/cUs4vVJ6
CPP File: http://pastebin.com/B5KUXTvx

Comment: Seems if one should work, the other should.  Can you show us your WndProc? You said initialise(sp) is private and getting called from WM_CREATE. Is wndproc a static member function? where is object being created?

Comment: I've attached links to full source.

Comment: Sounds like your `this` pointer is incorrect.

Comment: @AlfP.Steinbach How is that even possible? Such things can't happen in C# :(

Comment: @Ozzah: see Joe McGrath's answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Welcome to world of win32 that was not designed for C++.  That's a good first try. I redid classes trying to make a generic framework hundreds of times before saying it was not worth any more time.

Your WinMain() would also be helpful, but a big issue i see is your call to `CreateWindowEx()` . The last parameter you send is 0.  Than when you retrieve it later `SetWindowLong(hWnd, GWL_USERDATA, (long) ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);` you are saying it is a pointer to class. Did you mean to have:

```
         hWnd = CreateWindowEx(0, TEXT("AS2MainWindow"),
                                              TEXT("AS2"),
                                              WS_BORDER | WS_CAPTION | WS_SYSMENU | WS_MINIMIZEBOX,
                                              CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,
                                              824, 350,
                                              0, 0,
                                              hInstance, this);
```

Looking for other problems. See if that helps. If not maybe your post your main()

**Added:**
CreateWindowEx

```
HWND WINAPI CreateWindowEx(
  __in      DWORD dwExStyle,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpClassName,
  __in_opt  LPCTSTR lpWindowName,
  __in      DWORD dwStyle,
  __in      int x,
  __in      int y,
  __in      int nWidth,
  __in      int nHeight,
  __in_opt  HWND hWndParent,
  __in_opt  HMENU hMenu,
  __in_opt  HINSTANCE hInstance,
  __in_opt  LPVOID lpParam
);
```

The last parameter `lpParam` is optional. So when you had it set to 0 it was not hurting anything.  But this is how you "send" something to your `WM_NCCREATE` or `WM_CREATE`. It can be any LPVOID.  In C you may send a pointer to a struct or anything you want.  In this case you want to send it a pointer to the object that is about your window.

To get this parameter in WM_NCCREATE or WM_CREATE you use the below code:

```
(long) ((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams);
```

That is saying cast `lParam` to a `pointer` to a `CREATESTRUCT`.  Than get `lpCreateParams` from it. and cast that to a `long`.  This is slightly different than how i have written this  hard to understand piece of code.  If you break it into several steps it looks easier. Let me know if you need further explanation here.

Just so you get the full picture below is the definition of CreateStruct.  It has more than just lpCreateParams in it. (which you chose to be a pointer to your class).

```
typedef struct tagCREATESTRUCT {
  LPVOID    lpCreateParams;
  HINSTANCE hInstance;
  HMENU     hMenu;
  HWND      hwndParent;
  int       cy;
  int       cx;
  int       y;
  int       x;
  LONG      style;
  LPCTSTR   lpszName;
  LPCTSTR   lpszClass;
  DWORD     dwExStyle;
} CREATESTRUCT, *LPCREATESTRUCT;
```

After understanding all this. Check out ATL thunking.  Its the way to go if you want all your code inside classes.  I find it better to get away from EVERY piece of code being in a class when it doesn't have to be. Depends on the program I am writing.

Comment: That seemed to fix it! Why do I need to pass a `this` in CreateWindowEx even though I'm setting the pointer with `SetWindowLong`? What is the difference between these two pointers?

Comment: added to answer because fairly long explaination.

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out! It's because when I go `((LPCREATESTRUCT)lParam)->lpCreateParams` that has to come from somewhere, and that is from the `this` pointer I give to `CreateWindowEx`, right? :)

Comment: right.  You are getting it better than most. Check out ATL thunking you seem to have a good grasp on what's going on.  Than switch to linux and only answer win32 questions on here :)

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: It's actually quite possible to make a pretty good, wrapper on top of the Windows API that's more than just thin wrappers. (I've done it once already, and so has Qt and wxWidgets.) But it's definitely not trivial since the WinAPI was designed when C++ was "C with Classes" back then.

Comment: @Insilico Agreed. I have many opinions on WinAPI  (good and bad), but they would go way outside the scope of this question and intended purpose of this site. So i will stop myself :)

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: this is why people use the VCL - a great OO wrapper around the WinAPI.  (In silico, Qt isn't native, is it?)  Ozzah, if you want a good OO wrapper around native Windows windows and controls, and if you're not tied to Microsoft tools, try [C++ Builder and the VCL](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/cbuilder).

Comment: @DavidM Qt uses [native controls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qt_(framework)#Use_of_native_UI-rendering_APIs). If you haven't checked it out in awhile it's alot better than it use to be. If i had to pick one for it's use of native API  it would be [wxwidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/)  I learned plain win32 and I think it's good to understand it before you try to use a framework. I Though C++ builder was dead. Their website shows otherwise. Such a corporate looking site about a framework called "Fire Monkey" makes me laugh though.

Comment: @JoeMcGrath: yeah, it is a funny name :)  (It's weird: they target corporate markets, but have a name like that... trying to be cool maybe?  Or maybe it's just that you don't need to sound so formal with your product names these days.)  It's far from dead though!  I use it at work - very happy with it.  Good IDE, cross-platform compilation, good forums and community... and not to flog a dead horse, but the VCL is outstanding and one of the main reasons to use it, I think it's the main reason it was chosen a few years ago by my predecessors.